# How to use internal Roslyn classes?

Tags: c#, .net, api, compiler-warnings, roslyn

What is correct way for using Roslyn API in analizers? 
Let say I need to fetch info from context.Symbol and it is a field.
So it is obvious I can cast it to IFieldSymbol but I need to check initializer text. How I can get properties of underlying SourceFieldSymbol? It is Internal!

Reflection ? ;))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that.
Roslyn has a well-design public API which should be able to do anything you need (except at the editor level).

In this particular case, you should use the [`DeclaringSyntaxReferences` property](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,147).

In general, you can use http://sourceroslyn.io/ to follow the tree of references to an internal property and find the public API.

Comment: Yeah I expected that api is good but how to reach initializer of field?

Comment: Sorry man :) You absolutely right the API design is very good. In My case I have to use different handler : context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeObjectInitializer, SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration);   and something like fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables[n].Initializer